# I'm struggling to install netiq framewark manager

Tags: windows, server, netiq

I just installed netiq pam manager in my windows server 2016 but I'm struggling on how to reach the web console.
I tried to go to https://ip-adress but always give me 404 error
I disabled the firewall  completely but still no luck
Thanks